# How can I remove unwanted columns from a csv file using PapaParse in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem to remove unwanted columns from an uploaded CSV file. I have a CSV file that contains more than three columns, but I need the first three columns and want to avoid the rest of the columns.

Can anyone help me with this code?
Thanks...

**This is my full code:**

```
  const handleFileUpload = (files) => {
    if (files.length) {
      var file = files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onload = function (event) {
        var csvData = event.target.result;
        var data = Papa.parse(csvData, {
          header: true,
          dynamicTyping: true,
          skipEmptyLines: true,
          transformHeader: (header) => header.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, "_"),
        });
        let rows = data.data;
        let employees = [];
        const pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        employees = rows.filter((row) => row.first_name != null && (pattern.test(row.email.toLowerCase())));
        handleInsertToDatabase(employees);
      };
      reader.onerror = function () {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
      };
    }
  }
```

**The output of this code like below:**

```
{f_name: "fname", l_name: "lname", email: "fname@gmail.com", age: "20",...}
```

**But I need first the three columns:**

```
{f_name : "fname", l_name: "lname", email: "fname@gmaul.com"}
```

Comment: I see that the first and last object with 3 key-value pairs that you provided do not have the exact same keys, would like to ask if there is any typo error there. Also, if they happen to be the same, do you always expect your 3 keys to be `first_name, last_name, email` or could it be something else depending on the format of the csv file you’re reading in?

Comment: Yes!this is type mistake and want to 3 column, however csv file contain more then columns

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your json is read into a variable called `data`, you can get an object with the first 3 columns of `first_name, last_name, email` in 2 steps. I will use a smaller example to illustrate. The first step is to destructure the required key-value pairs using the key, which stores the values inside a variable equivalent to the key name in the json. This is feasible for a json of 3 elements.

```
const data = {f_name: "fname", l_name: "lname", email: "fname@gmail.com", age: "20"}
const { f_name, l_name, email } = data;
```

After which, you can create a new object with only those 3 pairs by adding their respective variables. The key in the final json will be the variable name you have added, which has the same name as the key in the initial json. The value in the final json would also reflect the same value as the initial json.

```
const required = { f_name, l_name, email }
```